# trouble with PHP to Excel

Tags: php, excel

before i asked here my coding first,

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=T1/T2.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
?>

<table width="100%"" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
  <td>+62-21-5900755</td>
  <td>2017-11-01</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

When i'm starting running this code, well is working, but my problem is the output not same on php. like `+62-21-5900755` change into `-5900714` and date `2017-11-01` change into `01/11/2017`. How to make my output excel same value as input on php???

Found Solution (Well not really too)
So add type `'` on first string, and you will get format became like these `'+62-21-5900755` and `'2017-11-01`. Thanks Vityata.

Comment: `HTML` !== MS Excel.... Perhaps write an Excel native file format like BIFF or OfficeOpenXML, or even a CSV file, rather than relying on MS Excel's HTML Importer to recognise that `+62-21-5900755` is a string value and not a formula

Comment: @MarkBaker I know thats why i wanna know is there solution, if there's not i might doin use `'` on first string.

Comment: `I wanna know is there solution`: `Perhaps write an Excel native file format like BIFF or OfficeOpenXML, or even a CSV file`

Comment: @MarkBaker : Well my client want format as xls. Yeah kinda odd :/

Comment: So then write a genuine BIFF format xls file, not html markup because that is simply html markup masquerading as an xls file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<table width="100%"" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
  <td>'+62-21-5900755</td>
  <td>'2017-11-01</td>
</tr>
```

The `'` part will leave it converted as a text.

Comment: Well i know that, but i mean is there another option besides input `'`?? cause i'm affraid my client wanna to make export to datatbase beseide my excel.

Comment: @Wolfzmus - generally two options - either format the cells in excel, once it enters there or format exactly before exporting to the DB. Furthermore, most of the good DBs would kindly ignore the `'` sign, they are made from really clever people :)

Comment: lol i knew it you gonna answer that. So the option is must manual at excel. Well i guess i'm using `'` that. Tq for that :)

Comment: @Wolfzmus - you can change the format in Excel through VBA. It is quite a trivial task.

Comment: Well my client need hurry up. So i cant make program using VBA again. :/